# Entity Framework 6 eager loading

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to load entities from a table into the local cache to display them in a grid control in the application window. The grid control gets its data from the `Local` property of the `DbSet<>`. The entities have a collection of subentities which also need to be loaded in advance because lazy loading won't work on the `Local` entities somehow.

The entity class has all mapped properties `virtual` and extended change tracking proxies are being used.

Here's what I've found:

```
myContext.Components.Include(x => x.Parts).ToList();
```

This is not supported, in fact the compiler throws an error because there is no `Include` overload that accepts anything else than a string. I have no idea why everybody shows code with expressions here if EF doesn't offer that. So here's what I've done instead:

```
myContext.Components.Include("Parts").ToList();
```

Unfortunately this has no effect at all. When I look into the Parts list, it's always empty:

```
var firstEntity = myContext.Components.Local.First();
var count = firstEntity.Parts.Count;
// count should be > 0 but is = 0
```

Specifying a different, nonexisting path for the `Include` method throws an exception at runtime, so EF really does look at that path string and validates it.

After accessing the `Parts` list, some time later, the parts will be in the list, but that's too late, and I don't know where they come from.

So what's the thing with the expression-parameter `Include` method, and why doesn't it work at all? What else do I have to consider to use eager loading?

Entity framework 6.1.3 (most other content seems to be for older versions).

Here are the classes:

```
public class Component
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Part> Parts { get; set; } = new List<Part>();
}

public class Part
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int PartId { get; set; }

    public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

    public virtual int RequiredCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you put your models code also ? `Components` and `Parts` ?

Comment: Are you `using System.Data.Entity;`? This is the namespace where `IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path)` is defined.

Comment: @Sampath I've added the classes.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Oh thanks, that was missing! I typed it anyway and expected Visual Studio to suggest me the using, but there was no light bulb this time. So expressions now work.

Comment: But the Parts list is still empty?

Comment: hope you have found the solution no ?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Seems it was my fault. There were really no associated items and the list was filled at a later stage of the code. Maybe I should reduce my question to the expression-Include part?